# foreach variable value is always the same

Tags: php, foreach

I'm working with an existing foreach that is stepping through an array of values pulled from the database. I'd like to perform some logic based on each key/value pair and assign some values to variables to output as part of the foreach loop.

Specifically I need to output the availability as determined based on some values for each key/pair. My logic works, but the value of the last record is assigned to EVERY record that passes the conditional tests, even if the values are different.

How can I assign $value['availability'] correctly for each time through the loop?

Here's my code:

```
foreach ($prices as $value) {
    if(!$this->_validateAttributeValue($attributeId, $value, $options)) {
        continue;
    }
    $currentProduct->setConfigurablePrice(
        $this->_preparePrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent'])
    );
    $currentProduct->setParentId(true);
        Mage::dispatchEvent(
            'catalog_product_type_configurable_price',
            array('product' => $currentProduct)
        );
        $configurablePrice = $currentProduct->getConfigurablePrice();

        if (isset($options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']])) {
            $productsIndex = $options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']];
        } else {
            $productsIndex = array();
        }

    /* Check the quantity */
    if($options['qty'][$value['label']] <= 0) {
        if ($product->getResource()->getAttribute('item_status')->getFrontend()->getValue($product) == "Preorder") { // Preorder
            $value['availability'] = "Pre-order";
        }
        elseif ($product->getResource()->getAttribute('item_status')->getFrontend()->getValue($product) != "Discontinued") { // Must be an active backorder item
            if ($product->getResource()->getAttribute('new_availability')->getFrontend()->getValue($product) != "No") {
                $value['availability'] = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('new_availability')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
            }
            else {
                $value['availability'] = "Temporarily out of stock";
            }                       
        }
    }

        $info['options'][] = array(
            'id'        => $value['value_index'],
            'label'     => ($options['qty'][$value['label']] <= 0) ? $value['label'] . ': '.$value['availability'].''  : $value['label'] . ": In stock",
            'price'     => $configurablePrice,
            'oldPrice'  => $this->_prepareOldPrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
            'products'  => $productsIndex,
        );
        $optionPrices[] = $configurablePrice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
foreach ($prices as $key=>$value){
   //your code
}
```

Comment: @Florin- Thanks for the suggestion, I'm still getting the same value for each trip through the loop though.